# filter on list of objects with inner hits

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to filter out a list of objects in elasticsearch

Assuming i am having below structure to map result status containing two objects

```
"SUBJECT_RESULT": [
            {
              "RESULT_STATUS": 101,
              "SUBJECT_ID": 194,
              "PERCENTAGE": 90
            },
            {
              "RESULT_STATUS": 102,
              "SUBJECT_ID": 19,
              "PERCENTAGE": "89"
            }
          ],
"STUDENT_ID": "123",
"CLASS_ID": "12"

"SUBJECT_RESULT": [
            {
              "RESULT_STATUS": 101,
              "SUBJECT_ID": 19,
              "PERCENTAGE": 90
            },
            {
              "RESULT_STATUS": 102,
              "SUBJECT_ID": 194,
              "PERCENTAGE": "95"
            }
          ],
"STUDENT_ID": "126",
"CLASS_ID": "12"
```

i want to filter students with subject id 19 and result status 101, so the expected output will be

```
"SUBJECT_RESULT": [
            {
              "RESULT_STATUS": 101,
              "SUBJECT_ID": 19,
              "PERCENTAGE": 90
            }
          ],
"STUDENT_ID": "126"
```

And the current output is

```
"SUBJECT_RESULT": [
            {
              "RESULT_STATUS": 101,
              "SUBJECT_ID": 194,
              "PERCENTAGE": 90
            },
            {
              "RESULT_STATUS": 102,
              "SUBJECT_ID": 19,
              "PERCENTAGE": "89"
            }
          ],
"STUDENT_ID": "123"

"SUBJECT_RESULT": [
            {
              "RESULT_STATUS": 101,
              "SUBJECT_ID": 19,
              "PERCENTAGE": 90
            },
            {
              "RESULT_STATUS": 102,
              "SUBJECT_ID": 194,
              "PERCENTAGE": "95"
            }
          ],
"STUDENT_ID": "126"
```

Below is the elastic query i tried which gives me the above mentioned output

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "CLASS_ID": [
                    "12"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "SUBJECT_RESULT",
                        "query": [
                          {
                            "terms": {
                              "SUBJECT_RESULT.SUBJECT_ID": [
                                "19"
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "terms": {
                              "SUBJECT_RESULT.RESULT_STATUS": [
                                "101"
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 5,
  "from": 0,
  "_source": [
    "STUDENT_ID",
    "SUBJECT_RESULT"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the `terms` query for `SUBJECT_RESULT.SUBJECT_ID` and `SUBJECT_RESULT.RESULT_STATUS` inside a `filter`/`must` clause of a `bool` query. Secondly since `SUBJECT_RESULT` is a nested object, you should add [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-inner-hits) in the nested query to get only the matching nested document and remove "SUBJECT_RESULT" from `_source` as it will return all the nested docs for matching parent document.
Below is the required query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "CLASS_ID": [
                    "12"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "SUBJECT_RESULT",
                        "inner_hits":{},
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "terms": {
                                  "SUBJECT_RESULT.SUBJECT_ID": [
                                    "19"
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "terms": {
                                  "SUBJECT_RESULT.RESULT_STATUS": [
                                    "101"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 5,
  "from": 0,
  "_source": [
    "STUDENT_ID"
  ]
}
```